# AWS Cognito iOS login delegate method `didCompleteStepWithError `not called

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am implementing AWS Cognito login in my swift based iOS app, however the delegate method `didCompleteStepWithError` is not triggered.

CognitoLoginViewController

```
class CognitoLoginViewController: UIViewController, AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!

    var user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser?
    var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?
    var passwordAuthenticationCompletion: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    //MARK: - IBAction
    @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
        if ((self.txtEmail.text?.isEmpty)! || (self.txtPassword.text?.isEmpty)!) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Missing information",
                                                    message: "Please enter a valid user name and password",
                                                    preferredStyle: .alert)
            let retryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(retryAction)
            self.navigationController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let authDetails = AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails(username: self.txtEmail.text!, password: self.txtPassword.text!)
            self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: authDetails)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func signup(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = CognitoSignUpViewController(nibName: "CognitoSignUpViewController", bundle: nil)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func forgotPassword(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = CognitoForgotPasswordViewController(nibName: "CognitoForgotPasswordViewController", bundle: nil)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }


    //MARK: - AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication delegate methods
    public func getDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput, passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>) {
        self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion = passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource
    }

    public func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = error as? NSError {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: error.userInfo["__type"] as? String,
                                                        message: error.userInfo["message"] as? String,
                                                        preferredStyle: .alert)
                let retryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(retryAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
            } else {
                self.txtEmail.text = nil
                //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The button click is triggered and the following lines are executed.

```
let authDetails = AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails(username: self.txtEmail.text!, password: self.txtPassword.text!)
self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: authDetails)
```

AppDelegate

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var rootNavigationController : UINavigationController?
    var loginViewController: CognitoLoginViewController?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        navigationInit()
        awsCognitoInit()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func awsCognitoInit(){
        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion,
                                                                identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolId)
        let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1,
                                                           credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
        let poolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId,
                                                                        clientSecret: CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret,
                                                                        poolId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolId)
        AWSLogger.default().logLevel = .verbose
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration
        AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: poolConfiguration, forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
    }

    func navigationInit() {
        self.rootNavigationController = UINavigationController()
        let loginViewController = LoginViewController()
        self.rootNavigationController!.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: false)

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window!.rootViewController = rootNavigationController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    //MARK: -
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }    
}
```

I am however able to use the signup, forgot password and code confirmation successfully. Also the cognito configuration values are correct since the above mentioned other operations are working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you confirmed `getDetails` is actually called to setup the `passwordAuthenticationCompletion` object?  Normally to trigger the auth flow to start you need to do something like `userPool.currentUser().getSession()` which will call `getDetails` as necessary or if an active session or refreshToken is already cached, use that.

Comment: you are right, `getDetails` isn't called. I tried to call `userPool.currentUser().getSession()` in the `viewDidLoad ` of the view controller but that also doesn't trigger the `getDetails` call. Am I placing the `getSession` call at the correct place.

Comment: Did you set the delegate on your user pool to the class that implements  AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate? pool.delegate = ...

Comment: hi can you please share your code, AWS Cognito iOS login delegate method `didCompleteStepWithError `not called